# Visual Studio will not compile community extension because ToolkitToolWindowPanel could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have tried to compile the visual studio 2022 extension with Tool Window. I have followed along in the video by Mads Cristianson to create the project.

[image]

I have the extension developer installed.

But in Visual studio I see this.

[image]

This is the compile error I am receiving

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ToolkitToolWindowPane' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VSIXWithToolWindow  C:\temp\Extensions\VSIXWithToolWindow\ToolWindows\MyToolWindow.cs   22  Active

I have tried to register the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell assembly as well with no luck

Browsed to this folder

`cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"`

```
gacutil -i .\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

(At time of writing) this is a bug in the released template, but it has been fixed in the [source code repository](https://github.com/VsixCommunity/Samples/blob/master/ToolWindow/ToolWindows/MyToolWindow.cs) for the toolkit.

The specific problem is that `ToolkitToolWindowPane` needs to be renamed to `ToolWindowPane`, but once that is fixed you'll find there are further problems with the released code. You'll need to update the project  with the code from the source repository, and ensure that the Nuget package references within your project are updated to the latest versions.

Note however that there are some parts of the source code (GUIDs and names) that need to be unique to your package so it doesn't clash with any others built from the same source code - check the differences between your templated project and the original `source.extension.vsixmanifest`, `VSCommandTable.vsct`, `VSCommandTable.cs` to see what needs to be changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following ways:

1.Try to reproduce creating a new project and check if the problem persists.

2.After closing Visual Studio and deleting the .vs folder under the project folder, reproduce the project to compile.

3.Add a reference to `Microsoft.Visual Studio.Shell` to the project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOzbh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWkn7.png)

4.Try repairing Visual Studio using the Visual Studio installer or resetting Visual Studio using Devenv/Resetting

**Update**:
Use `internal class Pane: ToolWindowPane` instead of `internal class Pane: ToolkitToolWindowPane`

Comment: I have already tried everything mentioned. This is something specific with the Extension Template pack 2022. It might be something specific with the computer, I am trying to run the compile the code on.  Something else ight be  causing the conflict.

Comment: Hi Stuart Smith, any updates to your issue? And have you found a specific cause for the problem.

Comment: Hi @Zhengye Xu , No I do not have a solution for this one as of yet.

Comment: Hi @Stuart Smith, I didn't find the toolkittoolwindowpane class in the official documentation, maybe you can try this: <internal class Pane: ToolWindowPane>

Comment: Hi @Stuart Smith, just wanted to confirm if there is any progress on your issue and if you have tried the advice I provided.  (Use <internal class Pane: ToolWindowPane> instead of <internal class Pane: ToolkitToolWindowPane>)

Comment: I found another way around my issue. Thank you for the help. I was trying to create a dynamic menu and found another way around the issue.

Comment: Hi @Stuart Smith, Glad you found the workaround, maybe you can share your method here and mark it as accepting the answer, as it will benefit other members who get the same or similar issues :) .

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could explain your workaround. Because unfortunately I'm experiencing the exact same problem as described in your question :(

Comment: @ZhengyeXu-MSFT: regarding your third hint: This isn't possible for me: `A reference to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.`

Comment: I was trying to create a button that toggles on and off via code, this led me to this solution going by a video by Mads kristensen But I then found this solution that add theme buttons.  https://github.com/madskristensen/ThemeSwitcher. This was not exactly what I wanted but close enough so I could get the job done.

Comment: @Jan Köhler, I just updated my answer, maybe you can try the method I updated.

Comment: @ZhengyeXu-MSFT: your answer seems too close to "Try turning the machine off and turning it on again"...generically useful attempts with little relationship to the actual problem.  I had the same problem and solved it with Jason William's approach (just editing my own code, though, not going back to the source code repository).